# How to 'restart' a sumif formula within an Arrayformula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, sumifs

I'd like to achieve the output below. Everything is manually added, except the starting time (and Day Nr). This should be calculated with the use of Arrayformula. It's working for 1 day, but now i'd like to add more days (manually). The duration should sum the day start + durations for only the specific day. When a new day row is inserted, it should start over new.

I'm using this code now, but only working with the starting time of Day 1 (the first row).
[Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73970332/how-to-reference-to-a-previous-row-within-a-column-with-arrayformula-in-google-s/73971569#73971569) below thanks to [doubleunary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13045193/doubleunary)

```
=arrayformula({"START"; 
   if(C3:C="DAY";E3:E;  
      if( 
      isnumber(H3:H); 
      vlookup("DAY";C3:E;3;true) + sumif(row(H3:H); "<=" & row(H3:H); H2:H); 
iferror(1/0) 
))
})
```

[This is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iEFZx0HIUMZA65vxX5aGERrrtDjpoUR7h_au5wl4F7A/) to the google doc

| Type (manual input) | Day Start (manual input) | Day Nr (calculated) | Starting Time (calculated) | Duration (input manual) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Day** | 08:00 | 1 |  | ------------ |
| Clip |  | 1 | 8:00 | 1:20 |
| Clip |  | 1 | 9:20 | 1:00 |
| Clip |  | 1 | 10:20 | 0:20 |
| Clip |  | 1 | and so on... | and so on... |
| **Day** | 7:30 | 2 |  |  |
| Clip |  | 2 | 7:30 | 2:00 |
| Clip |  | 2 | 9:30 | 1:40 |
| Clip |  | 2 | 11:10 | 0:20 |
| Clip |  | 2 | and so on... | and so on... |

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: I've updated the post with the link to the source and author's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the new Scan function to reset the addition of times:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C3:C<>"Clip",,
vlookup(row(C3:C),filter({row(C3:C),E3:E},C3:C="Day"),2,true)+
scan(0,if(C3:C="Day",-1,H2:H),lambda(a,c,if(c<0,0,a+c)))))
```

[image]

In your locale it should be:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(C3:C<>"Clip";;
vlookup(row(C3:C);filter({row(C3:C)\E3:E};C3:C="Day");2;true)+
scan(0;if(C3:C="Day";-1;H2:H);lambda(a;c;if(c<0;0;a+c)))))
```

Comment: I get the following message. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Error
The size of the range for FILTER is incorrect. Expected number of rows: 30, expected number of columns: 1. Current number of rows: 15, current number of columns: 1.

Comment: I've added a second tab (sheet) with your solution, maybe you see something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In the curly brackets, the ; becomes a \ in your locale. Will add to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(B2:B<>"",,IF(ISTEXT(E2:E),,{0;
 TEXT(VLOOKUP(ROW(B2:B), IF(B2:B<>"", {ROW(B2:B), B2:B}), 2, 1)+
 SUMIF(ROW(E2:E), "<="&ROW(E2:E), E2:E)-SUMIF(C2:C, "<"&C2:C, E2:E), "[h]:mm")}))))
```

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C3:C="";;IF(E3:E<>"";;IF(ISTEXT(E3:E);;{0;
 TEXT(VLOOKUP(ROW(E3:E); IF(E3:E<>""; {ROW(E3:E)\ E3:E}); 2; 1)+
 SUMIF(ROW(H3:H); "<="&ROW(H3:H); H3:H)-SUMIF(E3:E; "<"&E3:E; H3:H); "[h]:mm")}))))
```

Comment: I'm getting a VLOOKUP out of range message. I've added a second tab (sheet) with your solution, maybe you see something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @MarcelBuunk use 2nd formula. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629